# How to dynamically add scripts, styles into head with php

Tags: php, html

how to add dynamically scripts or styles in head with php.

i have pages on site that loads different scripts/styles based on logic needed on that page, how to append head and insert dynamically code?

On .net i would use placeholders for this, is there any way to do that with php (not javascript).

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: I don't fully understand this question the way it is worded. You want to include scripts using `<script src="**"` on a page but need PHP to decide when to do so? If so this is easy. I just don't want to write out an answer if I don't understand the question for sure.

Comment: you can use some `<?php $scripts = '<script src="your.js" type="text/javascript"></script>';?> <head><?php echo $scripts;?></head>`

Answer (score 1):

You make your (for example) if-condition at the location where you want to set something in (or set not it), the you can use

```
include_once(additionalcodefile.php);
```

for php-includes

or render css-links with

```
print "<link rel=[.....]>";
```

and, similar, js:

```
print "<script type=[.....]>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a file with the HTML you want, so for example a file like this **(and that's all that would be in the file)**:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="someStyleSheet.css" />
```

and you could name it something like `dynamicSheet.php`. Then in the PHP file in which you want to use it do something like this:

```
<?php
    if (some condition is true) {
        include_once(dynamicSheet.php);
    }
?>
```

Comment: is there way to do like this: on some page <?php loadStyle('url_to_style.css') ?>? thanks

Comment: @Danielp, no, you're including HTML and so PHP has no knowledge of that. You simply have to tell PHP to `include` a *file* and it will simply render what's in the file. However, `include_once` is restricted to including PHP files.

Comment: @Danielp, no problem, I'm glad I could be of assistance!